# Mesh appears inside out

Tags: mesh

I am modeling the monstercat character but when I look at what I have, I can see the inside of it instead of outside. How can I make the outside of the mesh show instead?

Comment: it might be my eyes playing tricks on me

Comment: could you put up a picture of your mesh?  Maybe try hitting ctrl-N

Comment: the pic is too big of a file

Comment: I meant a screen shot.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: im making it for animation so eventually im going to rig it but i figured it out